# Will my criminal record in the UK show up on my background check in Australia?

Tags: background-check, australia

I got deported from the United Kingdom due to my criminal conviction. I now live in Australia to start a new life. I am applying for jobs here and I was wondering if they perform a background check, would my criminal record in the UK show up?

Comment: Isn't that, like, what Australia is all about in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

I think it would depend on how thorough the background check they perform is. If they know you lived in the UK and they are thorough with the background check it would show up. I can't find anything that suggests an Australian company couldn't request a UK background check. However I would hope that a bank would spend more effort checking you out than a coffee shop so you might find you come back clean if they just do a very basic check on you.

Essentially though if you don't declare the conviction you'll almost certainly face dismissal if it's discovered at a later point and it is amazing how these things can come to light. Obviously I don't know the nature of your conviction but if you do want to make a fresh start then perhaps being honest about your past is the best approach.